# ASP.NET DropDown returning value of SelectedText instead of SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net

What am I missing?
I am constructing dropdowns, like this, from code-behind:

```
 ListItemCollection oL = new ListItemCollection();
        foreach (var item in edata)
        {
            ListItem oListItem = new ListItem();
            oListItem.Text = item.StatusName; //"StatusName"
            oListItem.Value  = item.Id.ToString(); // "StatusId"

            if(item.Id == statusid)
            {
                oListItem.Selected = true;
            }
            oL.Add(oListItem);

        }
```

But when I try to pick SelectedItem.Value like this, it should return StatusId but it is returning StatusName. What am I missing?

```
EventStatusDropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value
```

Comment: It is bad form to update your post in a way that invalidates existing (correct) answers. Please think through your question before posting, and include restrictions you have up front. It is not fair to Amit to exclude his solution after he already spent time writing it and posting it.

Comment: Did you check if ID and Name are different values in your List and not same?

Comment: yes both having diffrent values

Answer (score 0):

What does `edata` stand for here? If it is a `DataTable` or generic `List`, you can use `DataSource` and `DataBind` members. See the code below:

```
var edata = SomeMethodReturnngDataTable();
EventStatusDropDownList1.DataSource = edata;
EventStatusDropDownList1.DataTextField = "StatusName";
EventStatusDropDownList1.DataValueField = "StatusId";
EventStatusDropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Now you can use `EventStatusDropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value` to get the ID.

Comment: i was using this previously, bu now i have to use the way i mentioned. Yed edata is a list of object

Comment: Please take your time and rephrase that. It is really hard to follow your reasoning.

Comment: For example, you say you had to change your implementation from this, to the way in your original question. Why?

Comment: @UzmaGelani mmmm, add one more thing to above. After databind, write
EventStatusDropDownList1.SelectedValue=  statusId .ToString(); Entire code will first bind the dropdown then set the value to datasource. One thing to keep mind that such databinding controls support IEnumerable collections for databinding.